# Direct Implications Between USA and UK in Event of No-Deal Brexit

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, brexit

It is heavily discussed what sort of impacts could be expected in the United Kingdom and European Union in the event of a no-deal Brexit.  Less noted are any impacts this could have on the United States's economy, citizens, and other interests with concern to the UK.  In the event of a no-deal Brexit, do these countries have any sort of prepared treaties/agreements, or would certain aspects of the relationship between the countries need to be redrawn from scratch?

It may be the case that the future relationship between the UK and USA does not depend on the sort of Brexit that occurs, which would also be appropriate to mention here.

Answer (score 12):

In the immediate, basically none whatsoever. The [TTIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transatlantic_Trade_and_Investment_Partnership) is not signed yet.

Longer term, the implications are huge. The EU economy is only slightly smaller than the US, so it can arm wrestle it or stand firm on points it finds important. The UK in contrast, is large on the world scene compared to Zimbabwe, but puny compared to the US economy. The two negotiating a deal, and perhaps even more in Trump US, is akin to an 800 pound gorilla negotiating how to share a meal with a chihuahua.

> In the event of a no-deal Brexit, do these countries have any sort of prepared treaties/agreements

Not officially, since the EU is in charge of negotiating trade deals on its members' behalf, but one might imagine there's work being done to that effect behind closed doors.

> Or would certain aspects of the relationship between the countries need to be redrawn from scratch?

Per above, not from a trade standpoint, which is the main EU prerogative. Things like defense treaties are still done by the UK in its own name.

Comment: On the other hand, bilateral negotiations between the UK and USA only have to care about issues actually important to those countries. That is, the UK can't be forced to make treaty concessions in exchange for a provision that benefits, say, France or Germany instead. So, it's still not clear that the UK would be a in a worse negotiating position. The 800 lb gorilla v. chihuahua comparison also seems a bit extreme. Yes, the US economy is definitely larger than the UK, but the UK is still the 5th-largest economy in the world.

Comment: Also, the [US economy](https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/gdp) is actually larger than [that of the EU](https://tradingeconomics.com/european-union/gdp), even with the EU still including the UK, at least according to the most recent (2017) data. It will be around 30% larger than the EU economy after the UK leaves the EU.

Comment: @reirab: My bad. For some reason I seemed to remember the EU economy was slightly larger. You are correct, it's slightly smaller. Edited the answer accordingly. (I do stand by the fact that the UK will get clobbered into something terribly not in its favor if it tries to engage in trade negotiations with the US.)

Comment: The UK's GDP is much bigger than you think it is.

Comment: An important point that you missed is that the US economy after the Second World War was roughly 50% of world GDP. This was a high-point and it has been steadily decreasing since then. The future is likely to be multipolar rather than unipolar.

Comment: And this will be important in strengthening both global civil society and institutions.

Comment: @RonJohn: On the contrary, I suspect it is you who don't realize how small it it. The UK economy is roughly the size of those of that of India and France. The US economy is more than twice the size of the latter three combined.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy the UK economy is 14% the size of the US economy.  Chihuahuas weigh 0.6% of an 800lb gorilla.

Comment: @RonJohn: You're digging into whether a chihuahua is 14% of a gorilla's weight or not is a straw man. My toddler is about 14% of my weight too, and no amount of throwing tantrums will make me nudge when I've made up my mind on something.

Comment: Denis, your analogy is just **too** extreme.